# Is maprdb a document store or a key value store

Tags: optimization, mapreduce, hbase, mapr, nosql

I know that mapr db exposes OJAI interface to query using json documents and hbase api's using which we can create column families.
I want to know how does mapr db store data on file system, and what kind of queries are costly and what kind of queries are cheap (for which maprdb is really made for).

```
 It would be really helpful if some one can give some guidelines on what basis should we create column families if we are using hbase api's to access maprdb.

   Please share any references that can answer this question
```

Comment: You may have to go through the MapR Blogs and the MapR academy tutorials. For the time being, you can try this link http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Architecture+of+MapR-DB+and+the+Resulting+Advantages

Comment: @Prabhath Are you asking how MapR DB OJAI and MapR DB Binary (using HBase API) works and the differences between the two?